# Timer STM32 #error This code is designed to run on STM32F/L/H/G/WB/MP1 platform! Please check your Tools->Board setting

Tags: timers, stm32

I have installed the library of **[TimerInterrupt_Generic](https://github.com/khoih-prog/TimerInterrupt_Generic/)** for ArduinoSTM32 module via Arduino IDE, so i have tried to test the example of library as you can see below:

[image]
and i have gotten this error:

```
TimerInterruptLEDDemo:45:4: error: #error This code is designed to run on STM32F/L/H/G/WB/MP1 platform! Please check your Tools->Board setting.
   #error This code is designed to run on STM32F/L/H/G/WB/MP1 platform! Please check your Tools->Board setting.
    ^
In file included from /home/so/snap/arduino/current/Arduino/libraries/TimerInterrupt_Generic/examples/STM32/TimerInterruptLEDDemo/TimerInterruptLEDDemo.ino:64:0:
/home/so/snap/arduino/current/Arduino/libraries/TimerInterrupt_Generic/src/TimerInterrupt_Generic.h:86:4: error: #error Unsupported Board! Please check your Tools->Board setting.
   #error Unsupported Board! Please check your Tools->Board setting.
    ^
exit status 1
#error This code is designed to run on STM32F/L/H/G/WB/MP1 platform! Please check your Tools->Board setting.
```

Also, This question is asked here:

https://github.com/khoih-prog/TimerInterrupt_Generic/issues/2

Answer (score 4):

The [**Roger Clark's STM32 core**](https://github.com/rogerclarkmelbourne/Arduino_STM32)  you're using is not currently supported. I don't know in the future if I can add that core into the supported list.

You have to use this [**Arduino_Core_STM32**](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32).

Convert to new core by following the intructions in [**Getting Started**](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32#getting-started)

Comment: I have not installed the [rogerclarkmelbourne](https://github.com/rogerclarkmelbourne/Arduino_STM32), my STM32 Module is [stm32duino](https://github.com/stm32duino/Arduino_Core_STM32), but your suggestion for changing the STM32 board module is working and solved the [TimerInterrupt_Generic](https://github.com/khoih-prog/TimerInterrupt_Generic/), problem.